# What's different between "ResponseCache attribute" and "ResponseCache middleware" in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, caching, asp.net-core-middleware, responsecache

I know `ResponseCache attribute` can caching page in client side by http headers attribute `cache-control`.

And `ResponseCache middleware`, it caching page on server (same http headers as `ResponseCache attribute`).

I compare these, it seems no different, same features, same condition.

Server side caching is no different from `ResponseCache attribute`, they both don't let the request into controller action, or these have different request pipeline ?

So, What kind of scenarios would choose `ResponseCache middleware`/ `ResponseCache attribute`?

Answer (score -1):

From documentations and source code, we can find:

> **[Response Caching Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-3.1)**
>
> determines when responses are cacheable, stores responses, and serves responses from cache.
>
> **[ResponseCache Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-3.1#responsecache-attribute)**
>   specifies the parameters necessary ***for setting appropriate headers*** in response caching.
>
> It is used to configure and create (via IFilterFactory) a ResponseCacheFilter. The ResponseCacheFilter performs the work of updating the appropriate HTTP headers and features of the response. The filter:
>
> - Removes any existing headers for Vary, Cache-Control, and Pragma.
> - Writes out the appropriate headers based on the properties set in the ResponseCacheAttribute.
> - Updates the response caching HTTP feature if VaryByQueryKeys is set.

For more information, please check:

- [ResponseCachingMiddleware source
  code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/9a3aacb56af7221bfb29d851ee6b7c883650ddf6/src/Middleware/ResponseCaching/src/ResponseCachingMiddleware.cs#L91)
- [ResponseCacheAttribute source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ResponseCacheAttribute.cs#L132)